How I know the usage cost for each API key in Deepgram
I have the problem with api key usage for Deepgram service.
We support the speech to text service to customer companies with different API keys in Deepgram.
I can see and check log of usage. But I have to collect to report and request to payment for api key usage to each companies.
I can see and check log of usage. But I have to collect to report and request to payment for api key usage to each companies.
How can we know the api key usages based on key?
Is there any program for it?
Please help me.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
